# Compare List<string> and enable the required control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I am having two `list<string>` as follows

`listA` is having the following values `10,20,30,40`  and

`listB` is having the following values `10,20,30`

If `listB` contains `listA` elements i would like to enable particular controls if not i would like to disable the Controls

I tried of using two loops as follows

```
for(int ilist1=0;ilist1<listA.count;ilist1++)
{
  for(int ilist2=0;ilist2<listB.count;ilist2++)
  {
      if(listA[ilist1]==listB[ilist2])
      {
           //Enable particular control
      }
  }
}
```

But i know this is not an appropriate one to do so can any one tell me the best approach to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to hash the items in the first list into a set then verify for each item in the second is within the set.  Unfortunately the `HashSet<>` is not available so the closest you can get is the `Dictionary<,>`.

Do this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> set = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string item in listA)
{
    set.Add(item, item);
}

foreach (string item in listB)
{
    if (!set.ContainsKey(item))
    {
        //Enable particular control
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy by using the Intersect method:

```
    if (listB.Intersect(listA).Count() > 0)
    {
        //enable Control
    }
    else
    {
        //disable control
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
List<string> lista = new List<string>() {"10","40","30" };
List<string> listb = new List<string>() { "10", "20" };

var diff = listb.Except<string>(lista);
```

diff should give you the ones which didn't match else all would have been matched.

For 2.0

```
if (listb.TrueForAll(delegate(string s2) { return lista.Contains(s2); }))
                MessageBox.Show("All Matched");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Not Matched");
```

Answer (score 1):

In fx 2.0, you can do it like this:

```
    string b = listA.Find(delegate(string a) { return listB.Contains(a); });
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(b))
    {
        //disable control
    }
    else
    {
        //enable control
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Control.Enabled = listB.Intersect(listA).Any()
```

Note that Any() will only check to see if there is at least one item. Count() > 0 will evaluate the entire collection when you only need to check if there is at least one item

Edit: If you are in a .NET 2.0 environment then you can loop through and do this:

```
foreach (int item in listB)
{
    if (listA.Contains(item))
       return true;
}

return false;
```